# ngb datepicker hover issue

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap, ngb-datepicker

there is a filter form in my project which will filter the data on the basis of date range of ngbdatepicker. there is submitt and clear button. submitt button will appply the filter on data and clear button will clear the filter and will clear the date range in datepicker. but when we click the clear button it clear the range but when we click to again apply filter than it is showing little grey hover on recent picked date just to show the recent date picked. is it really a bug or bydefault functionality of ngbdatepicker

I am expecting date when i click on clear button it should not show the litle grey hover on recent picked date.

Comment: please share minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Comment: @NarenMurali   Clear() {
    this.form.reset();
    this.toDate =  null, // this.todayDate
    this.fromDate = null, // this.todayDate;
      FromDate: null, // this.parserFormatter.format(this.todayDate),
      ToDate: null, // this.parserFormatter.format(this.todayDate),
      Duration: null
    };
    this.loadCalls();
  }